# What is happening in this while loop condition?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
count=0
while(count==10):
    print("The count is:",count)
    count+=1
```

Why the above code is not showing any results or any error even. Whether the given condition(expression) is false? someone, please elobaorate how python is handling this condition.

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand your question but on that code, the loop will not run at all because the condition will always be false (10 != 0). It will just pass as if it didn't exist.

Comment: This code would make more sense if you did `while(count < 10)`. As stands, count is 0, not 10 so the loop never runs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your  kind response. In the code, instead of above condition, if I put while(count<10) or while (count<=10) , it will the execute the code right? So while loop before execution it testing the TRUE condition. So 0<10 and 0<=10 is TRUE condition and 0>10 or 0==10 is FALSE that's why the code is just passed.

Comment: "if I [change the code this way], it will [do something], right?" Well, did you **try it**? What happened? Anyway, if you want to understand the fundamentals, you should be following a tutorial, not trying to ask on Stack Overflow. It would take hundreds of questions like this in order to learn the basics, and every one of them would be better answered by just following the tutorial. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum and is not intended as a tutorial resource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read how the `while` loop works . While loop would execute the code till the condition is true. In your case `count==10` is never satisfied, hence next two statements are not executed.
Changing the condition would execute the code.

```
count=0
while count < 10:
    print("The count is:",count)
    count+=1
```